# "Long" with telic intransitive verbs expressing duration

Tags: intransitive-verbs

When I try to express duration with intransitive verbs indicating a complete event, like "expire" or "melt", it works if I add "long" like:

> The license has long expired.

But not:

> The license has expired for two years now.

or

> The snow has melted for two days now.

How is it that adding the indefinite time expression "long" makes the sentences sound more natural?

(I know that there are a lot of alternative ways to say this same, like: "The licence is two years past its expiry date" or "The license hasn't been renewed for two years now" or "The license expired two years ago" or "There hasn't been  snow for two days now"..)

Comment: Rejlan, where is you research and what is the conclusion you're trying to test, please?

Isn't your Question really, *would it still work if you did not add 'long'* and isn't the answer, *obviously*?

Adding *long* does not make anything sound more natural. I can't prove that negative but If you doubt it, please explain.

How do you think *… expired for two years/days* with or without a *now* are comparable to *… long expired*, please?

Comment: Interesting. The [Collins CoBuild entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/long_1) << **long** [domain: time] ... 1. adverb [modifies verb](a) _a great amount of time_ or (b) **for**  _a great amount of time_ : (a)[negative polarity item] _Repairs to the cable did not take too long / Have you known her parents long?_ //(b).. _Chess has long been regarded as a measure of intellect._ [modified]>> does not seem to address the 'long ago' sense you mention ('It has long expired') or the adjective-modifier sense ('He is long dead'). But notice that the former is a punctive usage.

Comment: "The license has long expired" just sounds wrong to me.